# Can cards turned face-down by Ixidron be turned face up again?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-face-down-cards

For example, assume that both my opponent and I have a face-up creature with Morph on the battlefield.

I cast [Ixidron](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIxidron%5d) and it enters the battlefield.

Can both creatures be turned face-up again later in the game, by paying the Morph cost, even though they weren't turned face-down "normally"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

It doesn't matter how a creature got turned face-down. All morph cares about is that the creature is indeed face-down. Face-down is a status like e.g. tapped/untapped.

> 110.6. A permanent’s status is its physical state. There are four status categories, each of which has two possible values: tapped/untapped, flipped/unflipped, face up/face down, and phased in/phased out. Each permanent always has one of these values for each of these categories.
>
> 702.36a Morph is a static ability that functions in any zone from which you could play the card it’s on, and **the morph effect works any time the card is face down.** [..]

Comment: Note that if those creatures do not have morph, then there is normally no way to make them turn face-up again by themselves. You will have to use other cards to turn them back, or make them leave the battlefield and return (in which case they will return face-up unless explicitly told otherwise).